# NotMapped attribute is ignored if property has also another attribute

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, devexpress

My entity class has a property of type `DateTime` with `[NotMapped]` and `[DateRange]` attributes. `[DateRange]` attribute is from DevExpress.

When I try to create a new migration then `[NotMapped]` attribute is ignored and entity framework wants to create a new column for this property.

If the second attribute `[DateRange]` is removed then `[NotMapped]` is working.

I've tried EF 6.2 and 6.3 but with the same result.

Not working:

```
public class Foo
{
    [Required]
    public DateTime DT1Utc { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public DateTime LocalDT1
    {
      get => TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(DT1Utc, TimeZoneInfo.Local);
      set => DT1Utc = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(value);
    }

    [Required]
    public DateTime DT2Utc { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    [DateRange(StartDateEditFieldName = "LocalDT1", MinDayCount = 1)]
    public DateTime LocalDT2
    {
      get => TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(DT2Utc, TimeZoneInfo.Local);
      set => DT2Utc = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(value);
    }
}
```

Working:

```
public class Foo
    {
        [Required]
        public DateTime DT1Utc { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public DateTime LocalDT1
        {
          get => TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(DT1Utc, TimeZoneInfo.Local);
          set => DT1Utc = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(value);
        }

        [Required]
        public DateTime DT2Utc { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public DateTime LocalDT2
        {
          get => TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(DT2Utc, TimeZoneInfo.Local);
          set => DT2Utc = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(value);
        }
    }
```

Comment: are the using directives the same in both cases? You might be having a ambiguous NotMapped in there.

Comment: using directived are the same in both cases.

Comment: Which .net version are you on?

Comment: I'm on .net 4.7.2